# PHP How do i calculate number of month in Year

Tags: php

> I want to calculate how many number of months in particular year? For example
>   In 1.5 year how many month are ? It's simple but programmatically how do i calculate this??
>   Please can anybody tell me??

Comment: `$m = $y * 12;`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of Year(s), `1.5`, you would calculate this by multiplying it by the number of Months in a year, `12`.

```
function calcMonths($y){
  return $y * 12;
}
```

Input: 1.5, Output: 18.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Start Date and End Date then it will easy to calculate months between those two dates try below Code.

```
$date1 = '2000-01-25';
$date2 = '2010-02-20';

$ts1 = strtotime($date1);
$ts2 = strtotime($date2);

$year1 = date('Y', $ts1);
$year2 = date('Y', $ts2);

$month1 = date('m', $ts1);
$month2 = date('m', $ts2);

echo $diff = (($year2 - $year1) * 12) + ($month2 - $month1);
```